# Echo value from array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, echo

I am running a query on a wordpress database to count the number of occurences of the value 'apple' in the wp_fruit table like so...

```
$count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_fruit WHERE value='apple'" );
```

which returns....

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#446 (1) { ["count"]=> string(3) "238" } } Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 238 ) ) array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#445 (1) { ["count"]=> string(3) "238" } } Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 238 ) ) array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#446 (1) { ["count"]=> string(3) "238" } } Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 238 ) )
```

The value I am after is 238, how do I echo this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$count` is an array of row objects, in this case only one:

```
echo $count[0]->count;
```

It might make more sense if you use `$row` instead of `$count`.

```
echo $row[0]->count;
```

So you are accessing the count column (object property) of the first row (row 0).